# Recursive Locking in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

Can anyone explain what is meant by recursive locking in Java?

Many thanks

Comment: 'Recursive' locking would mean that a locking routine calls itself, which doesn't make much sense. Do you mean 'reentrant' locking? Please quote the text that you are trying to understand.

Comment: To understand recursive locking you first have to understand recursive locking

Answer (score 1):

recursive locking in java means the same thread can lock the same mutex object twice and won't deadlock

Answer (score 0):

Intrinsic locks in Java are reentrant. Recursive locking is the single method (correct me if I'm wrong) to ensure "hand-over-hand" locking using intrinsic locks.

Comment: Hand over hand locking uses multiple lock objects (whether monitor or j.u.c.Lock), which can cause deadlocking.  Recursive locking uses the same lock with the same thread multiple times

Comment: John, I was thinking of a scenario using the intrinsic lock of a guarding LOCK object to navigate a tree vs locking the entire tree. This is where lock reentrancy comes into play